# how eureka peers guarantee the registration information is consistent when sync action fail

Tags: netflix-eureka, paxos, gossip

[PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/4f24d9dcf90713b421f6c092fa63e707cbf74df3/eureka-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/eureka/registry/PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl.java) will sync to other peers when registration changed,the code as follows:

```
private void replicateInstanceActionsToPeers(Action action, String appName,
                                             String id, InstanceInfo info, InstanceStatus newStatus,
                                             PeerEurekaNode node) {
    try {
        InstanceInfo infoFromRegistry = null;
        CurrentRequestVersion.set(Version.V2);
        switch (action) {
            case Cancel:
                node.cancel(appName, id);
                break;
            case Heartbeat:
                InstanceStatus overriddenStatus = overriddenInstanceStatusMap.get(id);
                infoFromRegistry = getInstanceByAppAndId(appName, id, false);
                node.heartbeat(appName, id, infoFromRegistry, overriddenStatus, false);
                break;
            case Register:
                node.register(info);
                break;
            case StatusUpdate:
                infoFromRegistry = getInstanceByAppAndId(appName, id, false);
                node.statusUpdate(appName, id, newStatus, infoFromRegistry);
                break;
            case DeleteStatusOverride:
                infoFromRegistry = getInstanceByAppAndId(appName, id, false);
                node.deleteStatusOverride(appName, id, infoFromRegistry);
                break;
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.error("Cannot replicate information to {} for action {}", node.getServiceUrl(), action.name(), t);
    }
}
```

I am confused about the distributed consistency of multiple eureka servers。when replicate action fail。it just catch the throwable. Why not use consistency algorithms such as gossip,paxos to ensure a higher consistency?

I saw the desc of the [wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-Eureka-Peer-to-Peer-Communication) and know that eureka just let it in temporary inconsistency。 the server tries to be as resilient as possible。Aha cap theory!

Comment: I saw the desc of the wiki and know that eureka just let it in temporary inconsistency。 the server tries to be as resilient as possible。Aha cap theory!